# Which of the following sentences is correct? And what is the striking contrast among them?

Tags: modal-verbs, comparative-constructions, minor-sentences

Which of the following sentences is correct? And what is the striking contrast among them?

> 1) The richer you are , the happier **you can be**.
>
> 2) The richer you are, the happier **you will be**.
>
> 3) The richer you are, the happier **you are**.

Comment: What makes you think any of them is *incorrect*?  And what do you think the contrast is?  Without more detail this question will likely be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Modal **can** refers to a strong likelihood as distinct from the definite. The definite is expressed by **will be** and **are**.

> The darker it gets, the harder it can be to see.
>
> The darker it gets, the harder it {is|will be} to see.

The difference between those two sentences is subtle.  The first, with **can**, states that darkness makes it harder to see if not in all cases then in most cases: as a "rule of thumb", darkness makes it harder to see; the evidence is not in doubt but it falls shy of making an absolute statement. The second, with **is** and **will be**, is a starker statement: darkness makes it harder to see. The modal **will** emphasizes the *result*  or *outcome* that flows from the fact, in this kind of construction.

Answer (score -1):

**All** of them are **correct**, depending on the message that you want to convey:

> The richer you are , the happier **you can be**.

It means that the level of your general **happiness potential** depends on your richness **now or generally**.

> The richer you are, the happier **you will be**.

Unlike the previous one (using the modal verb "can") It means that the level of **your happiness in the future** depends on your richness **now or generally**.

> The richer you are, the **happier you are**.

Unlike the previous two (using in can and will), this one means that the level of **your happiness generally** depends on your richness **generally**.

Comment: -1. I downvoted because the present tense here refers to a general state of affairs, not to the present moment.  The richer you are *at any time*...

Comment: Thank you for your note. Let me know if I have other mistakes to correct and I'll do it happily.